# sync persistence_token across databases

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, authlogic, synchronization

I am trying to figure out how to sync authlogic persistence tokens across servers.

I have 4 servers, and I have many apps on all 4, the authentication is working across all the apps on one server.  I can even get them to work on different servers if I copy the persistence token from one to the other 3.

The only issue I can think of is users may login to one server and not the other, but I still want them to be able to be synced in case they do go to that other server.  For example:

Joe logs into server 1

Joe also logs into server 2

Jane only logs into server 1

Fred only logs into server 2

I would need a 2 way sync from each of the servers.  I don't care which persistence token they get as long as they are all the same.

This also uses LDAP for authentication in case that matters.

I am open to pretty much any suggestion, including something non-rails related.

**Edit**

To update this, I cannot remove LDAP authentication.  I really have no desire to replace authlogic.  I was thinking of something like a rake task or shell script to handle the syncing.

I am perfectly fine coming up with my own idea, just want to see if someone knows the best way.

Thank you all for any help.

Comment: You might want to investigate using a DB session store, or perhaps using a Memcached session store if that seems too heavy handed. Your question seems kind of open-ended, so what is your goal? When you say "server" do you mean "site"?

Comment: I guess I didn't really make it clear what I required.  I will update the question with what is required.  When I say server I mean a linux box running apache and mysql, and multiple apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might really be looking for a central authentication service (CAS) -- something that will enable Single Sign On (SSO).

This enables you to log on to different services. It will work something like

- User requests http://server1
- server1 checks if the user is authenticated against the local store. If not:
- server1 redirects user to something like http://casserver?return=server1
- casserver actually gets the username/password or credentials, authenticates them, and:
- casserver redirects to http://server1

Then:

- User requests http://server2
- server2 redirects user to http://casserver?return=server2
- casserver redirects user to http://server2 with the authtoken

That way the user does not enter credentials more than once.

OAuth works like this (over-simplified)

People have used the [java based CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) . Some posts:

- http://weblog.plexobject.com/?p=1682
- http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2007/01/08/cas-sso-and-rails.html

Comment: We are very rural, and internet is not reliable. What if casserver is down?  server2 cannot authenticate.  Also it seems like you are suggesting some sort of authentication token that is generated by casserver, how does server2 know what that should be?  Thank you for your suggestions, but I do not think they will work in this case.

Comment: 6 months later and this is the solution I am going with.  Guess I just had to understand more about cas before I could get what you meant.